# Remove all traces of D-Bus when running Mousepad in Debian

Tags: debian, compiling, dpkg, deb

I am trying to rebuild Debian package `mousepad` without D-Bus on Debian 10.

First, I try building the package without any change.

```bsh
apt-get source mousepad
cd mousepad-0.4.1
dpkg-buildpackage --build=binary --no-sign
```

That works.

Now I want to build with D-Bus disabled. I see that Mousepad has the `--disable-dbus` build option, but where exactly should I put it?

The `debian/rules` file looks like this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/make -f

export DEB_LDFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND=-Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-z,defs
export DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS=hardening=+all

override_dh_missing:
    dh_missing --fail-missing

override_dh_autoreconf:
    mkdir -p m4
    dh_autoreconf

%:
    dh $@
```

When I launch Mousepad on Debian 10, I see the following messages in the log.

```
dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=10430] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.0' (uid=1000 pid=10425 comm="mousepad ")  
dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=10430] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
```

Therefore, I believe the standard package Mousepad on Debian 10 does use D-Bus and it starts the `dbus-launch` binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Debian 10 `mousepad` package is already built without D-Bus support; you can verify this by looking at [the build logs for version 0.4.1-2 on `amd64`](https://buildd.debian.org/status/fetch.php?pkg=mousepad&arch=amd64&ver=0.4.1-2&stamp=1541884432&raw=0) and searching for “D-BUS”:

```
Build Configuration:

* D-BUS support:             no
* Debug Support:             minimum
* Use keyfile backend:       default
* Build with GTK+ 3:         yes
```

To make this explicit, you need to override the automatic configuration; add this to the end of `debian/rules`:

```
override_dh_auto_configure:
        dh_auto_configure -- --disable-dbus
```

Make sure that the second line starts with a tab.

The log messages you’ve found come from `dconf`, not Mousepad itself; to disable those, you can try switching to the keyfile settings backend:

```
override_dh_auto_configure:
        dh_auto_configure -- --without-dbus --enable-keyfile-settings
```

While you’re at it, add a `changelog` entry to make sure that your package won’t get “upgraded” to the same `dbus`-enabled version from the repositories:

```
dch --local +400cat 'Rebuild without dbus.'
dch -r ignored
```

(this uses `dch` from the `devscripts` package).

Now build the package:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

and install it.

This will still result in a binary which depends (indirectly) on `libdbus-1.so.3`, but that’s because it depends on `libgtk-3.so.0`, which itself depends on `libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0`, which depends on `libdbus-1.so.3`.

If you really want to get rid of D-Bus, you’ll have to rebuild [`at-spi2-atk`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/at-spi2-atk), and anything else on your system which build-depends on `libdbus-1-dev`.

Comment: thank you. Using `--enable-keyfile-settings` solved it. What exactly have I changed, by using this option? The comment in the source code only says: "Use the GSettings keyfile backend rather than the default". What is the other, default backend?

Comment: The default is `dconf-gsettings`, which relies on D-Bus to talk to the GSettings service.

Comment: can I specify to use the GSettings keyfile backend when building other packages? I have currently another question open for evince (with bounty):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533967/debian-package-build-fails-for-evince-when-using-the-disable-dbus-option/68987133#68987133